# Did household conversions recorded in the Bible include teenagers and children?

Tags: acts, 1-corinthians, baptism

There is no evidence of teenager or child baptisms in the New Testament.
All candidates are adults.

However, the book of Acts and 1 Corinthians mention the conversion of the entire household of Crispus.

> Acts 18:8 Crispus, the ruler of the synagogue, believed in the Lord,
>   together with his entire household.

Should we conclude that a household conversion implies teenager and child baptisms?

Comment: Unfortunately this question does not seem a good fit for our site, because there is no text for us to perform hermeneutics.  It could work if you changed the question to include the specific passage you want us to answer on. In the meantime, please take the [tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not already done so, and see what questions work well.

Comment: I will then provide the Bible verses.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it essentially starts from an 'idea' with texts added for support rather than arising naturally from a particular text.

Comment: @JackDouglas You're my hero on the site, Jack! But I will have to disagree w/you on this one; the understanding of the text precludes it's praxis. While we may all favor a particular rendering of it's meaning, a Good Answer can interpret the text within it's context. Centuries of debate have challenged it's application, but as a site we must be able to answer these "textual questions" and not appear 'squeamish' to the fact that they may border on theology.

Comment: Thanks @Tau you are too kind :) I could be persuaded on this one with an edit that narrows it down to one of the verses in particular like Acts 16:15 — the other verses could be referred to but I don't think the question should ask equally about them all.

Comment: I narrowed it down to Crispus' household.

Comment: It's still a broad question. Please refocus the question on that sole verse and household. If you want to find broad scriptural proof texting for credo- vs. paedobaptism, ask on [Christianity.SE]

Comment: Christianity did not invent the concept of baptism, and Jewish baptism of adult parents did not exclude their children.

Comment: Lucian, please provide us with Bible scriptures, thank you.